# ValueError at /ads/ad/2/comment

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to add comment to an Ad posted by a user. When I press the comment button, it is showing the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyRPw.png).
Here's my ***models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings 

class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
            max_length=200,
            validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "Title must be greater than 2 characters")]
        )
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #picture
    picture = models.BinaryField(null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, help_text='The MIMEType of the file')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    comments = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Comment', related_name='comments_owned')
    #show up in the admin list
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model) :
    text = models.TextField(
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(3, "Comment must be greater than 3 characters")]
    )

    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # Shows up in the admin list
    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.text) < 15 : 
            return self.text
        return self.text[:11] + ' ...'
```

Here's my ***forms.py***

```
# commentForm
from django import forms
from ads.models import Ad, Comment 
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from ads.humanize import naturalsize
from django.core import validators
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

...

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=500, min_length=3, strip=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']
```

Here's my ***views.py***

```
from ads.models import Ad, Comment
from ads.owner import OwnerListView, OwnerDetailView, OwnerCreateView, OwnerUpdateView, OwnerDeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from django.views import View 
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from ads.forms import CreateForm, CommentForm

class AdDetailView(OwnerDetailView):
    model = Ad

    def get(self, request, pk):
        a = Ad.objects.get(id=pk)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(ad=a).order_by('-updated_at')
        comment_form = CommentForm()
        context = {'ad': a, 'comments':comments, 'comment_form':comment_form}
        return render(request, 'ads/ad_detail.html', context)
....

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, pk):
        ad = get_object_or_404(Ad, id=pk)
        comment = Comment(text=request.POST['comment'], owner=request, ad=ad)
        comment.save()
        return redirect(reverse('ads:ad_detail', args=[pk]))

class CommentDeleteView(OwnerDeleteView):
    model = Comment

    def get_success_url(self):
        ad = self.object.ad
        return reverse('ads:ad_detail', args=[ad.id])
```

And finally my templates ***ad_detail.html***

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<br clear="all"/>
<p>
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'ads:ad_comment_create' ad.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form|crispy }}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="submit" value="All Ads" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'ads:all' %}'; return false;">       
    </form>
</p>
{% endif %}

{% for comment in comments %}
<p> {{ comment.text }}  
    ({{ comment.updated_at|naturaltime }})
    {% if user == comment.owner %}
    <a href="{% url 'ads:ad_comment_delete' comment.id %}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    {% endif %}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

After clicking on the submit button, it's supposed to be taking to `ads:all` but instead throwing an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyRPw.png).
In case you also want to check ***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AdListView.as_view()),
    path('ads', views.AdListView.as_view(), name='all'),
    ...
    #comments
    path('ad/<int:pk>/comment', views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='ad_comment_create'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/delete', views.CommentDeleteView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('ads')), name='ad_comment_delete'),
]
```

Comment: Your imgur image is not showing up.

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane I have updated the image link. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `CommentCreateView`, your owner is recieving `request` that was the reason you were shown that error. So:

```
comment = Comment(text=request.POST['comment'], owner=request.user, ad=ad)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `ModelForm` instead of `Form` here.

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=500, min_length=3, strip=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']
```

And change your view

```
 class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        ad = get_object_or_404(Ad, id=pk)
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.ad = ad
        comment.owner = request.user
        comment.save()
        return redirect('ads:ad_detail', ad.pk)
```